# Одновременная работа ajax + longpoll

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть сайт, на котором реализована работа с серверной частью(php) посредством ajax запросов. Все страницы находятся на одном домене, пользователь везде определяется через сессионные куки, последний номер события хранится там же.
К этому сайту был приделан longpoll, поддерживающий постоянное соединение с одной из страниц бэкенда, переподключение к странице после окончания ее загрузки(10 секунд), все работает как нужно.

Проблема в том, что если во время выполнения какого-то longpoll запроса вызвать еще один запрос, то он будет обработан только после возвращения результата от longpoll`a. 
На vk.com, допустим, все работает отлично, во время longpoll запросов без проблем отправляются еще и другие, не ожидающие окончания друг-друга. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно добиться точно такого же результата?

Comment: С вероятностью 90% у вас файл сессии блокируется PHP до конца запроса.

Comment: Попробовать сделать longpoll на отдельном поддомене с доступом по токенам?

Comment: Лучше просто использовать для сессии БД (по-моему в нативном хендлере блокировку просто так не отменить)

Comment: Решение:
В обработчике(php) перед частью, отвечающей за ожидание события: session_write_close();
Перед отправкой результата: session_start();